# Как сделать проверку по 2 условиям из JSON

Tags: python, json, telebot

Как сделать проверку по 2 значениям из json перед отправкой сообщения через telebot

Есть .json файл лежащий рядом с main.py

```
  {"employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "name": "Олег Олегов",
        "portalname": "test1",
        "role": "employee",
        "id": 1111111,
        "username": "Oleg",
        "department": "departament1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Андрей Андреев",
        "portalname": "test2",
        "role": "employee",
        "id": 2222222,
        "username": "Andrey",
        "department": "departament1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Иван Иванов",
        "portalname": "test3",
        "role": "employee",
        "id": 3333333,
        "username": "Ivan",
        "department": "departament1"
      }]}}
```

я его подключаю в проект

```
import telebot
import json
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    with open('employees_list.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        jsonData = json.load(file)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=["quest"])
    def quest_message(message):
        try:
            user_username = message.from_user.username
            user_id = message.from_user.id
            request_quest = '@' + str(user_username) + ' need quest'
            print(request_quest)
            print(message.text)
            answer = 'test'
            bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
            for i in jsonData['employees']['employee']:
                if i['department'] and user_id == 'departament1':
                    bot.send_message(admin_id, request_quest, reply_markup=gen_markup(str(message.from_user.id)))

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            bot.send_message(admin_id, "Error: " + str(ex))
```

Как сделать проверку что бы если юзер находится в department1 и его ID есть в json, то отправлялось сообщение по

`bot.send_message(admin_id, request_quest, reply_markup=gen_markup(str(message.from_user.id)))`

Answer (score 0):

Если в JSON в поле `id` записан user_id, то тогда так:

```
if i['department'] == 'departament1' and i['id'] == user_id:
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал немного по другому:

```
if any(employee['department'] == "departament1" and employee['id'] == user_id for employee in jsonData['employee']):
```